# Coalesce differently for different types of partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set that I want to partition by year and month.  Each year the number of records is about 10x larger in January than any other month.  According to documentation for Azure PySpark it's best to keep partitions between 200mb and 3gb.  If I decide to coalesce(10), for example, the sizes for Feb-Dec won't be in that ideal range, but the January ones will be fine.  If I coalesce(1), for example, the Jan file will be huge.

So the question is, can I coalesce a different number of files depending on the month value?

Comment: Split your dataframe into 2 dataframes, one with only January records and the other for the rest of records, now repartition each dataframe accordingly.

Comment: You could try `coalesce(1).write.option('maxRecordsPerFile', 50000)`. <= change the number for your use case.  This will try to `coalesce` to 1 file for smaller partition and for larger partition, it will split the file based on the number in option.

Comment: These are both helpful, @AbdennacerLachiheb and Emma.  I think both will work, and I'll test them both out.  Thanks for your help.